# Mostrar número de celular con Substring

Tags: java, android, substring

Hola a todos tengo una consulta que no puedo resolver hasta ahora:
tengo un dato que me trae números de la base de datos pero estos números están en este forma:

```
953448770/962521639
```

hice un comando con substring separando los números y me quedo asi:

```
String telefono1 = datosfono.substring(0,9);
--------------------------------------------

String telefono2 = datosfono.substring(10);
-------------------------------------------

Resultado: txtInfoSicmactele1.setText(telefono1);
---------------------------------------
```

y todo estaba yendo bien, pero ahora que estuve probando hay números que los digitan mal, por ejemplo:
-número de celular tiene 9 dígitos = 123456789

- los que escriben mal algunos tienen 7 u 8 dígitos

Entonces mi pregunta sería, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que pueda mostrar el número de celular no importa así esté mal escrito con 9 o 7, o los dígitos que tenga?
Ejemplo:
Mostrar : 123456789
o también se podría mostrar: 1234567

Comment: Hola taeguk, array o arreglo significan lo mismo, en idioma español vas a encontrar cualquiera de los dos terminos los cuales son validos, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una opcion viable seria que lo hicieras con un `.split()`

```
String cadenaCompleta = "953448770/962521639";
String[] numeros = cadenaCompleta.split("/");
System.out.println("Numero 1: "+numeros[0]);
System.out.println("Numero 2: "+numeros[1]);
```

asi lo puedes separar sin importar cual es la longitud de cada numero de telefono.

Comment: muchas gracias, me salvaste la vida.Pero ahora me genera un error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: Muestra los datos con los que probaste para ver cual puede ser el error. @taeguk

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener los numeros obteniendo un arreglo a partir de la cadena mediante `.split("/")` , pero para evitar un error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` y funcione para todos los casos, puedes iterar limitando a el numero de elementos en el array a partir del numero de elementos dentro del arreglo mediante `numeros.length`.

Ejemplo:

```
String telefonos = "829312/953448770/962521639/";
String[] numeros = telefonos.split("/");

for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
    System.out.println("Numero "+(i+1)+": "+numeros[i]); 
}
```

Salida:

```
Numero 1: 829312
Numero 2: 953448770
Numero 3: 962521639
```

Comment: gracias, si lo hice con un for parecido y me salio <3

Comment: Ahora tengo otro problema con este tema del split, tengo unos numero de celular que en ves de número solo tiene espacio, algo asi (" /") y asi si sale pero los otros numero que o tienen espacio salen asi (123456789/123456789) como puedo hacer para que me muestre los numeros separados asi solo contengan espacios en blanco???... por favor ayuda! :(